# Wordpress cant upload to wp-content/upload

Tags: wordpress, image, upload, media

So a client asked to make some changes to his wordpress site, I can install and run plugins, but when I try to put some images or pdf files into the media it gives me the following error: "cant upload to wp-content/upload". I have created an admin user but cant upload any media.

Answer (score 0):

Check if your "uploads" folder has the right permissions.
It should be at least `755`.

> Uploads folder is located at `/wp-content/uploads`

Comment: What do you mean by that? How do I see that?